# Cx_freeze Python 3.3 with SWIG

Tags: c++, python, cx-freeze

I plan to use SWIG (C++) together with Python 3.3; Tkinter as front end. The idea is to use Python to select a file (string), have C++ count the missing values, and return it as a string.

Will it be possible to combine this into a standalone application using cx_freeze? If possible, what would be the steps to take?

All I would like is for Python to send a file path *string* to the C++ side, which will then load the file (200,000 rows by 300 columns), count missings, and return a (python) *list*.

I stumbled into trouble when I tried using SWIG; it has a known error for python 3.3 that got me stuck. Maybe it would be better to just write a wrapper manually (SWIG might be overkill for just a simple function). Any ideas how to do that then?

Comment: It should be possible. Describing all the steps involved seems rather open ended for a SO question - can you be more specific?

Comment: You can also go for cython (which has C++ support) or make your function `extern "C"` and call the resulting shared library directly via ctypes.